# Modeling my Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

this is my first post on here. My question is pertaining to model relationships.

I'm new to rails and a bit confused as to what type of associations I need. I checked [rails associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) but this confused me more. I've tried quite a few things and can't figure out exactly what I need.

I have three [models/tables](http://cl.ly/image/1x141K111d1N):

1. Students
2. Teachers
3. Groups (as in classes)

I have it setup as:

teacher -> belongs_to :group

student -> belongs_to :group

group   -> has_many :students  &  has_many :teachers

This setup works okay because it allows me to make calls like:

g.students.all

s.group.name

However I would like to be able to make a view page that generates all of the Groups(classes) that a teacher has. Such as: t.groups.all or t.groups.count

One thing that makes my table unique is that a group(class) can have different teachers. I don't know if I need a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship or a has_many :through relationship.

What is the ideal setup for my 3 tables, what table id's and associations are required?

Comment: A teacher can have different groups as well? what about students and groups relation? Could you please explain it as well

Comment: the way it works is that a "group" will definitely have at least 2 "teachers". They can change on a weekly basis. However, a student will only have one "group"... although technically they could have 2 "groups". But for the sake of the original question it can be said that: A group has many teachers and a group has many students.

Comment: my question is still unanswered. Can a teacher have more than one group? can the students have more than one group?

Comment: ohh- Yes to both of them. A student could be in 2 different groups/classes. Every group/class could have a different combination of teachers of as well. A teacher can have an unlimited # of different groups.